# Unreachable statement on second switch statement using continue

Tags: java

So I made two switch statments inside a for loop, the first one has a default that has continue if none of the expected cases occur, therefore moving to the next invocation in the for loop. However when I create my second switch statement it states that it's unreachable. It's my understanding that that switch case is only unreachable if the case in the previous switch becomes true, and there are times when it's not. Below is the code.

```
for (int i=1; i < dataSize; i++)
{
            if (!(formatter.formatCellValue(findTitleContents(tempSpreadsheet,"Screen ID",i)).isEmpty()))
            {

                switch (formatter.formatCellValue(findTitleContents(tempSpreadsheet,"Masking(TB/SM)",i)))
                {
                    case "SM":  tempScreen.getTreeValue().remove(ScreenStatus.StatusFlag.TB);
                    case "TB":  tempScreen.getTreeValue().add(ScreenStatus.StatusFlag.TB);
                    default :   returnMessage += "Incorrect masking value for row: " + i + "\n, skipping";
                                continue;
                }
                //Unreachable statement
                switch (formatter.formatCellValue(findTitleContents(tempSpreadsheet,"3D?(Y/N)",i)))
                {
                    case "Y": tempScreen.getTreeValue().add(ScreenStatus.StatusFlag.IS3D);
                }

                screenList.add(tempScreen);
                tempScreen = new Screen();
            }
            else
            {
                logger.info("Skipping row: {}, no ID identified",i);
                returnMessage += "Skipping row: " + i +", no ID identified\n";
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You are missing the break statements in your cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you use `continue;` in `default` for the first `switch` and have no `break`,so `continue` will always work,you need add `break`

```
switch (formatter.formatCellValue(findTitleContents(tempSpreadsheet,"Masking(TB/SM)",i)))
{
    case "SM":  tempScreen.getTreeValue().remove(ScreenStatus.StatusFlag.TB);
     break;
    case "TB":  tempScreen.getTreeValue().add(ScreenStatus.StatusFlag.TB);
       break;
    default :   returnMessage += "Incorrect masking value for row: " + i + "\n, skipping";
                continue;
}

//Unreachable statement
switch (formatter.formatCellValue(findTitleContents(tempSpreadsheet,"3D?(Y/N)",i)))
{
    case "Y": tempScreen.getTreeValue().add(ScreenStatus.StatusFlag.IS3D);
}
```